# Load DropDownList from ViewData in MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-select, viewdata

I have the following View. This is the whole code of my view

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="clientDDL">
                    </select>
                    <% Html.DropDownList("clientDDL",
                        new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Clients"], "Code", "Name")); %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I use the next ViewData from my Model:

```
public static List<lookup> GetClients()
        {
            using (ModelDataContext data = new ModelDataContext(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                List<lookup> retVal = new List<lookup>();
                List<Client> lClient = data.Clients.Where(a => a.IsActive == true).ToList();
                lClient = lClient.OrderBy(o => o.ClientName).ToList();

                foreach (Client item in lClient)
                {
                    retVal.Add(new lookup() { Code = item.ClientID.ToString(), Name = item.ClientName, });
                }
                return retVal;
            }            
        }
```

This is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult ProcedureFilter()
        {
            ViewData["Clients"] = WorkflowModels.GetClients();
            return View();
        }
```

What did I miss? My DropDownList is still empty. Maybe i have to put some reference? Any suggestions please.

UPDATE:
The problem was ';' at the end of part <%= %>. The works code:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("clientDDL",
                            new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Clients"], "Code", "Name")) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ASP.NET code you provided, 2 HTML `select` tags (or DropdownLists) are defined with the same `id` (cliendDDL) :

```
   <select id="clientDDL"> <-- the first one
   </select> 
   <% Html.DropDownList("clientDDL",
      new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Clients"], "Code", "Name")); %> <-- the second one, Html.DropDownList generating a select under the hood.
```

Would it be possible that only the first one is displayed (the empty one) and the second remains hidden because of a missing character, changing your expected HTML generation routine (`Html.DropDownList`) into an [Embedded Code Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Maybe instead of :

```
<% Html.DropDownList
```

it should be :

```
<%= Html.DropDownList or <%: Html.DropDownList
```

See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) for <%:%> ASP.NET 4 syntax

**Edited**

Also the ";" end of line character is not needed and should be removed.

Comment: I've tried both your proposes, but nothing work. If I remove 1st select, I don't have ddl at all. If I use <%= I have an error...

Comment: From i see in this link (http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) <%= should be used and the ";" at the end is not needed. What is the error you get? Html.DropDownList should generate select tag for you, can you at least display an empty DropDownList using Html.DropDownList only?

Answer (score 0):

**View Page:**
"<%=Html.DropDownList("Description", New SelectList(ViewData("Description")), "--Select--")%>"

**Contoller:**

Function Purchase() As ActionResult:

```
    Dim dataContext As New tblMVCDataContext
    Dim teststr As String
    Dim itemVar = From U In dataContext.Items Select U.Description

    For Each tbItem In itemVar

        teststr += tbItem + ","
    Next
    ViewData("Description") = teststr.Split(",")
    Return View(itemVar)
End Function
```